# Block main thread until UIWebView finishes loading

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

I'm trying to block the main thread until a UIWebView finishes loading, but calling `[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:]` after calling `[UIWebView loadRequest:]` makes the loading never complete: The `webViewDidFinishLoad` delegate is called after the sleep finishes.

Why is this happening? and How can I block the main thread?
I'm calling `loadPage` from `[ViewController willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:]`, what I'm trying to do is to prevent the iOS interface to rotate until the webview with the other orientation is loaded.

```
- (void)loadPage {
    UIWebView* webview2 = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    webview2.delegate = self;

    NSString* htmlPath = ..... ; // Path to local html file
    NSURL *newURL = [[[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: htmlPath] autorelease];
    NSURLRequest *newURLRequest = [[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: newURL] autorelease];

    [webview2 loadRequest:newURLRequest];
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:10.0f]; // Why this blocks the uiwebview thread ??
    [self.view addSubview:webview2];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSLog(@"Finished loading!");
}
```

Comment: Not quite what you're looking for, but why not call `[[self view] addSubview:webView];` in `-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView`?

Comment: I want the interface to rotate just after the uiwebview finished loading.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to solve the wrong problem.

You don't want to block the main thread. Firstly, the entire UI is drawn on the main thread, so it will appear as though your app has hung. Secondly, a UIWebView is part of the UI (which is probably why what you're doing doesn't work).

So, what to do?

Have a look at the following method:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

When you start loading your page you can return `NO` from this method. When it's finished loading you can return values normally. `UIWebView` has a delegate that tells you the status.

Comment: But shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: will be called just once, when the user rotates the device, and if I return NO I can't force the rotation later when the webview has loaded.

Comment: And, I do want to block the UI... the webview will load in about half a second, I want the screen to freeze that time and then rotate nicely without the UIWebView showing the blank page.

Comment: Still, blocking the main thread isn't going to work. You'll either have to download the content in advance, or display a progress indicator or something like that. The whole idea of the iOS interface is that it's fluid and user-driven; you're effectively trying to defeat that.

Comment: I don't have to download the content... it's local

Comment: Why not just have two web views and switch between them when you change orientation?

Comment: @StephenDarlington has the ticket, IMO. You just need to add code to test the device orientation after the `UIWebView` loads and then react if it has changed. For that matter, you could also let `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` react by updating a flag to tell you that you need to adjust the UI when the `UIWebView` finishes loading. Either way, you're just delaying the work until you know it's ok to do it, which is what you want, and it's much simpler than trying to set timers or push work around between threads.

Comment: @strings42 That sounds good, but how do I perform the UI rotation at any time? I mean, on shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation I return NO, but load the UIWebView anyway, and when the load has finished I should force the rotation. How do I force it?

Comment: @StephenDarlington loading the 2 orientations is my second solution, but it would be way better to avoid it because every time the user changes the page I would have to load 2 pages. It's a magazine.

Comment: Or... cancel the loading the of the first web view on the orientation change and switch to the new one immediately. Locking the UI for even half a second is going to look really bad.

Comment: I think the fundamental problam, keeping the UI responsive without showing an intermediate view while waiting for the UIWebView to load data, is not realistic. Either you're going to have to show some kind of temporary view (an empty webView, the existing view, something) while you load your data, or you're at the mercy of the time it takes to get the data. I can't think of any way to bend the iOS space-time continuum to defeat that. ;-) Showing the data-less screen is in line with the Apple paradign of showing an unpopulated screen at app load, for what that's worth.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the class reference for [NSURLRequest](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsurlconnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html), there is a sync method in there.

```
+ (NSData *)sendSynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request returningResponse:(NSURLResponse **)response error:(NSError **)error
```

Comment: But the file I'm loading is local