# UIWebView threads crash after device rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiwebview

I have an application with several **UIWebViews** inside UITableViewCells that are rendering some locally loaded HTML, with some additional Javascript libraries applied (such as Prettify.js).

There is, at most, one UIWebView inside of a UITableViewCell. Things work well overall, except that, when I have many UIWebViews loading, and I **rotate the device back and forth**, I am getting repeatable crashes from `WebCore::RenderBlock`.

Some wacky ideas I have tried (and failed):

1. [Disable rotation while the UIWebViews are loading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10484785/504912)
2. Use dispatch_semaphor_t to prevent the rotation from happening.

   - This ends up blocking the main thread, a strategy which fails
     because UITableView updates have to occur on the
     main thread, resulting in a deadlock.
3. Use an NSOperationQueue to delay the tableView updates a bit if a rotation occur.

I am beginning to run out of ideas, and am looking for new approaches on how to attack this issue. Has anyone encountered this sort of issue before?

**My current conclusion** is that this occurs because of some **thread synchronization** problem between `UIWebView -> WebCore` and the UIKit rotation/rendering thread.

```
    thread #1: tid = 0x2355ad, 0x0077c976 libgmalloc.dylib`breakIfDebugging + 158, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread, stop reason = EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0)
    frame #0: 0x0077c976 libgmalloc.dylib`breakIfDebugging + 158
    frame #1: 0x0077cbcf libgmalloc.dylib`GMmalloc_zone_malloc_internal + 182
    frame #2: 0x0077bcfe libgmalloc.dylib`GMmalloc_zone_malloc + 161
    frame #3: 0x0077bb7f libgmalloc.dylib`GMmalloc_zone_calloc + 180
    frame #4: 0x0077b7a4 libgmalloc.dylib`GMcalloc + 58
    frame #5: 0x0d82f3cd libCGFreetype.A.dylib`(anonymous namespace)::allocate(FT_MemoryRec_*, long) + 25
    frame #6: 0x0d8311f5 libCGFreetype.A.dylib`ft_mem_alloc + 29
    frame #7: 0x0d841991 libCGFreetype.A.dylib`T1_Face_Init + 611
    frame #8: 0x0d832565 libCGFreetype.A.dylib`open_face + 155
    frame #9: 0x0d831fbe libCGFreetype.A.dylib`FT_Open_Face + 390
    frame #10: 0x0d826ccc libCGFreetype.A.dylib`(anonymous namespace)::open_face(FT::stream*, long, __CFString const*) + 79
    frame #11: 0x0d826e26 libCGFreetype.A.dylib`FT::font::create_fonts_with_path(__CFString const*) + 86
    frame #12: 0x0d82f536 libCGFreetype.A.dylib`(anonymous namespace)::create_private_data_with_path(__CFString const*) + 34
    frame #13: 0x009dffa8 CoreGraphics`CGFontCreateFontsWithPath + 44
    frame #14: 0x0090132e CoreGraphics`add_fonts_at_path_locked + 42
    frame #15: 0x0090229f CoreGraphics`fault_all_locked + 212
    frame #16: 0x00901e3f CoreGraphics`apply_function_locked + 42
    frame #17: 0x00901de3 CoreGraphics`CGFontDBApplyFunction + 77
    frame #18: 0x009e00a0 CoreGraphics`CGFontApplyFunction + 88
    frame #19: 0x00b8f87b CoreText`TDescriptorSource::CreateAllDescriptorsCache(void*) + 73
    frame #20: 0x032d84b0 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 14
    frame #21: 0x032c7e17 libdispatch.dylib`dispatch_once_f + 182
    frame #22: 0x00b8fb59 CoreText`TDescriptorSource::CopyCachedAllDescriptors() + 171
    frame #23: 0x00b8fb78 CoreText`TDescriptorSource::CopyAllDescriptorsInternal(bool, CFComparisonResult (*)(void const*, void const*, void*)) const + 26
    frame #24: 0x00b8fcdf CoreText`TDescriptorSource::CopyAllDescriptors() const + 79
    frame #25: 0x00b9153e CoreText`TDescriptorSource::CopyDescriptorsForRequest(__CFDictionary const*, __CFSet const*, CFComparisonResult (*)(void const*, void const*, void*), void*, unsigned long) const + 3040
    frame #26: 0x00b9070f CoreText`TDescriptorSource::CopySystemWideFallbackDescriptor(CGFont*, unsigned short const*, long, UIFontFlag) const + 797
    frame #27: 0x00b91f16 CoreText`TDescriptorSource::CopySystemWideFallbackDescriptor(CGFont*, __CFString const*, CFRange, UIFontFlag) const + 210
    frame #28: 0x00b7e8b6 CoreText`TFontCascade::CreateSystemWideFallback(__CTFont const*, __CFString const*, CFRange) const + 132
    frame #29: 0x00b7e35c CoreText`TFontCascade::CreateFallback(__CTFont const*, __CFString const*, CTEmojiPolicy) const + 1446
    frame #30: 0x00b53d0b CoreText`TGlyphEncoder::AppendUnmappedCharRun(TCFRef<CTRun*>&, __CTFont const*, CFRange, CFRange, TGlyphList<TDeletedGlyphIndex>&, TGlyphList<TDeletedGlyphIndex>&, TFontCascade const&, TGlyphEncoder::ClusterMatching) + 453
    frame #31: 0x00b538b7 CoreText`TGlyphEncoder::RunUnicodeEncoderRecursively(TCFRef<CTRun*>&&, __CTFont const*, CFRange, TGlyphList<TDeletedGlyphIndex>&, TGlyphList<TDeletedGlyphIndex>&, TFontCascade const*, TGlyphEncoder::ClusterMatching, bool) + 1443
    frame #32: 0x00b5326e CoreText`TGlyphEncoder::RunUnicodeEncoder(TCFRef<CTRun*>&&, __CTFont const*, CFRange, TGlyphList<TDeletedGlyphIndex>&, TFontCascade const*) + 166
    frame #33: 0x00b52c89 CoreText`TGlyphEncoder::EncodeChars(CFRange, TAttributes const&, TGlyphList<TDeletedGlyphIndex>&, TGlyphEncoder::Fallbacks) + 1257
    frame #34: 0x00b67a65 CoreText`TTypesetterUniChar::Initialize() + 355
    frame #35: 0x00b678c6 CoreText`TTypesetterUniChar::TTypesetterUniChar(unsigned short const* (*)(long, long*, __CFDictionary const**, void*), void (*)(unsigned short const*, void*), void*) + 178
    frame #36: 0x00b576ac CoreText`CTLineCreateWithUniCharProvider + 80
    frame #37: 0x07f79c4a WebCore`WebCore::ComplexTextController::collectComplexTextRunsForCharacters(unsigned short const*, unsigned int, unsigned int, WebCore::SimpleFontData const*) + 1674
    frame #38: 0x07f7503c WebCore`WebCore::ComplexTextController::collectComplexTextRuns() + 620
    frame #39: 0x07f749f8 WebCore`WebCore::ComplexTextController::ComplexTextController(WebCore::Font const*, WebCore::TextRun const&, bool, WTF::HashSet<WebCore::SimpleFontData const*, WTF::PtrHash<WebCore::SimpleFontData const*>, WTF::HashTraits<WebCore::SimpleFontData const*> >*, bool) + 696
    frame #40: 0x07f78ab8 WebCore`WebCore::TextLayout::TextLayout(WebCore::RenderText*, WebCore::Font const&, float) + 152
    frame #41: 0x07f7457a WebCore`WebCore::Font::createLayout(WebCore::RenderText*, float, bool) const + 170
    frame #42: 0x089baaa7 WebCore`WebCore::RenderBlock::LineBreaker::nextSegmentBreak(WebCore::BidiResolver<WebCore::InlineIterator, WebCore::BidiRun>&, WebCore::LineInfo&, WebCore::RenderBlock::RenderTextInfo&, WebCore::RenderBlock::FloatingObject*, unsigned int, WTF::Vector<WebCore::WordMeasurement, 64ul, WTF::CrashOnOverflow>&) + 6855
    frame #43: 0x089b42f7 WebCore`WebCore::RenderBlock::layoutRunsAndFloatsInRange(WebCore::LineLayoutState&, WebCore::BidiResolver<WebCore::InlineIterator, WebCore::BidiRun>&, WebCore::InlineIterator const&, WebCore::BidiStatus const&, unsigned int) + 583
    frame #44: 0x089b3438 WebCore`WebCore::RenderBlock::layoutRunsAndFloats(WebCore::LineLayoutState&, bool) + 1336
    frame #45: 0x089b6dbf WebCore`WebCore::RenderBlock::layoutInlineChildren(bool, WebCore::LayoutUnit&, WebCore::LayoutUnit&) + 2543
    frame #46: 0x089901de WebCore`WebCore::RenderBlock::layoutBlock(bool, WebCore::LayoutUnit) + 1614
    frame #47: 0x0898f541 WebCore`WebCore::RenderBlock::layout() + 81
    frame #48: 0x08997837 WebCore`WebCore::RenderBlock::layoutBlockChild(WebCore::RenderBox*, WebCore::RenderBlock::MarginInfo&, WebCore::LayoutUnit&, WebCore::LayoutUnit&) + 711
    frame #49: 0x08991b7b WebCore`WebCore::RenderBlock::layoutBlockChildren(bool, WebCore::LayoutUnit&) + 587
    frame #50: 0x089901f9 WebCore`WebCore::RenderBlock::layoutBlock(bool, WebCore::LayoutUnit) + 1641
    frame #51: 0x0898f541 WebCore`WebCore::RenderBlock::layout() + 81
    frame #52: 0x08997837 WebCore`WebCore::RenderBlock::layoutBlockChild(WebCore::RenderBox*, WebCore::RenderBlock::MarginInfo&, WebCore::LayoutUnit&, WebCore::LayoutUnit&) + 711
    frame #53: 0x08991b7b WebCore`WebCore::RenderBlock::layoutBlockChildren(bool, WebCore::LayoutUnit&) + 587
    frame #54: 0x089901f9 WebCore`WebCore::RenderBlock::layoutBlock(bool, WebCore::LayoutUnit) + 1641
    frame #55: 0x0898f541 WebCore`WebCore::RenderBlock::layout() + 81
    frame #56: 0x08997837 WebCore`WebCore::RenderBlock::layoutBlockChild(WebCore::RenderBox*, WebCore::RenderBlock::MarginInfo&, WebCore::LayoutUnit&, WebCore::LayoutUnit&) + 711
    frame #57: 0x08991b7b WebCore`WebCore::RenderBlock::layoutBlockChildren(bool, WebCore::LayoutUnit&) + 587
    frame #58: 0x089901f9 WebCore`WebCore::RenderBlock::layoutBlock(bool, WebCore::LayoutUnit) + 1641
    frame #59: 0x0898f541 WebCore`WebCore::RenderBlock::layout() + 81
    frame #60: 0x08af387e WebCore`WebCore::RenderView::layout() + 1374
    frame #61: 0x08253531 WebCore`WebCore::FrameView::layout(bool) + 1713
    frame #62: 0x080b0a64 WebCore`WebCore::Document::updateLayout() + 228
    frame #63: 0x080b40fa WebCore`WebCore::Document::updateLayoutIgnorePendingStylesheets() + 298
    frame #64: 0x0819a310 WebCore`WebCore::Element::offsetHeight() + 32
    frame #65: 0x085a9534 WebCore`WebCore::jsElementOffsetHeight(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSValue, JSC::PropertyName) + 20
    frame #66: 0x0a6ccb47 JavaScriptCore`JSC::JSValue::get(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::PropertyName, JSC::PropertySlot&) const + 727
    frame #67: 0x0a8eb309 JavaScriptCore`llint_slow_path_get_by_id + 233
```